# Exception In Xamarin Forms and Visual Studio - An unhandled exception occured

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

I'm developing an application in Xamarin Forms with Visual Studio 2017.
So far I have not faced any major issues, but now when I debug my application on the Android device, it always returns an exception that is not detected by try / catch.
There is not much information in the IDE about the fact, other than these:
1 - An unhandled exception occured.
2 - The selected debug mechanism does not support any code running on the current thread (eg only the native runtime code is running)
The error always occurs when I try to navigate to a registration confirmation screen where the user needs to enter a verification code. The "funny" is that when I do the same process on an emulator, none of this happens.
What might be happening and what is needed to correct the problem?

Below is a print with the exception on the screen.
[image]
Here is the code of the confirm page.

**//---XAML---\**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>``
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="FlipDigital.Views.FlipDigital_ConfirmarCadastro"
             Title="Confirmar Cadastro">
    <AbsoluteLayout>

        <!--#region Imagem de Background-->

        <Image x:Name="imgBackground" Aspect="AspectFill"
                Source="https://sites.google.com/site/clickemenow/arquivos/Background.png?attredirects=0"
                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="1,1,1,1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
                />

        <!--#endregion-->

        <!--#region Imagem Agencia-->

        <Image x:Name="imgAgencia"
            Source="logoflipdigital.png"
            WidthRequest="150"
            HeightRequest="150"
            BackgroundColor="Transparent"
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds=".5,0,.4,.3" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
        />

        <Label BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                    Text="Flip Digital" FontSize="22" TextColor="White"
                    x:Name="lbTitulo"
                    Opacity="0.9"
                    HeightRequest="60"
                    WidthRequest="50"
                    VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                    HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds=".5,.3,.8,.1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
               />

        <Label BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                    Text="Sua Agência OnLine" FontSize="16" TextColor="White"
                    x:Name="lbSubtitulo"
                    Opacity="0.9"
                    HeightRequest="60"
                    WidthRequest="50"
                    VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                    HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds=".5,.35,.8,.1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
               />

        <Entry BackgroundColor="White"
                    FontSize="18"
                    x:Name="txtCodVerificacao"
                    Placeholder="Codigo Veficador"
                    Opacity="0.6"
                    HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                    HeightRequest="60"
                    WidthRequest="50"
                    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds=".5,.5,.88,.1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
               />

        <!--#endregion-->

        <!--#region Bloco Cadastrar e Nova Senha-->

        <Button BackgroundColor="Teal"
                    x:Name="btnReenviar"
                    Text="Reenviar código" FontSize="15"
                    TextColor="White" Opacity="0.8"
                    HeightRequest="60"
                    WidthRequest="50"
                    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds=".1,.65,.4,.1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
               />

        <Button BackgroundColor="Teal"
                    x:Name="btnConfirmar"
                    Text="Verificar código" FontSize="15"
                    TextColor="White" Opacity="0.8"
                    HeightRequest="60"
                    WidthRequest="50"
                    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds=".9,.65,.4,.1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
               />
        <!--#endregion-->

    </AbsoluteLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

**//---C#---\**

```
namespace FlipDigital.Views
{

    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class FlipDigital_ConfirmarCadastro : ContentPage
    {

        public bool Agencia { get; set; }

        public FlipDigital_ConfirmarCadastro(bool agencia)
        {
            try
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                this.Agencia = agencia;
                btnConfirmar.Clicked += Seguir;
                //BindingContext = new ContentPageViewModel();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                DisplayAlert("Exception", ex.Message, "OK");
            }
        }

        private async void ReenviarCodigo(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Exception", ex.Message, "OK");
            }
        }

        private async void Seguir(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Alert", "Cadastro confirmado com sucesso. Você está sendo direcionado a pagina inicial do app.", "OK");

                if (Agencia)
                {
                    await Navigation.PushAsync(new FlipDigital_InicialAgencia());
                }
                else
                {
                    await Navigation.PushAsync(new FlipDigital_InicialCliente());
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Exception", ex.Message, "OK");
            }
        }
    }

    class FlipDigital_ConfirmarCadastroViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        public FlipDigital_ConfirmarCadastroViewModel()
        {
            IncreaseCountCommand = new Command(IncreaseCount);
        }

        int count;

        string countDisplay = "You clicked 0 times.";
        public string CountDisplay
        {
            get { return countDisplay; }
            set { countDisplay = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
        }

        public ICommand IncreaseCountCommand { get; }

        void IncreaseCount() =>
            CountDisplay = $"You clicked {++count} times";


        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = "") =>
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

    }
}
```

It is worth mentioning that the exception occurs only in this page, since the navigation of the others happens normally.

Comment: Add the full Exception/Error that appears in the application output (logcat)

Comment: The code is not C as tagged.

Comment: What's the actual exception?  You should be able to click "Break" when the unhandled exception dialog comes up and drop into the debugger to identify the exception and stack trace.

Comment: As shown in the image, no exception message is set on the console. Just what is set in the floating box that appears on the screen. The debugging process is also stopped at this point.

Comment: I have the same problem. Do not have detail in this message, only `An unhandled exception occured.` and no more. No **Inner detail**, nothing.

Comment: I got the similar kind of error in my xamarin.forms project. I was using calling functionality but I have not given the permission to call in android project in android manifest file . If you are using any native API functionality then check your permission. And also check on android options -> debugging option checked in visual studio 2017.